# How much lighter could a modern, working replica of an Apollo payload and crew be at launch?

Tags: apollo-program, materials

When I was young a zillion years ago I visited the Smithsonian's Air and Space museum, and admired what I think must have been a mercury capsule. Upon peering through the window, what struck me first was the construction. Thick plates of aluminum, large electrical components, etc. These were the materials and components of the era.

Fast forward to this [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26155/what-is-falcon-heavys-payload-capacity-to-trans-lunar-injection#comment77185_26155) speculating about the BFR's capability of putting an Apollo stack on its way to the Moon (it seems not to be possible).

I'm wondering, roughly, hypothetically, if one wanted to build a working replica of an Apollo Moon landing mission from current aerospace materials being used in spacecraft and land on the Moon with a crew as a sort of homage, how much lighter would it be?

One third lighter maybe? Could it be half the weight?

Would modern engines, electronics, or electromechanics (motors, pumps, etc) help a lot, or would it be mostly structural weight?

Comment: With modern engineering techniques you could probably get it down to 180% of the weight of the original.

Comment: Doesn't 180% of an original represent an increase?

Comment: @RussellBorogove your comment is intriguing but a bit cryptic. Is there a typo, or do you mean to say it would be almost twice as heavy as the original?

Comment: That's what I mean, yeah.

Comment: @RussellBorogove is referring, I think with his tongue firmly in his cheek, to current trends in government contractor aerospace design. +1

Comment: @RussellBorogove literally LOLed, just barely managed to refrain from the accompanying ROTF.

Comment: I'm not an aerospace engineer, so this is a comment instead of an answer, but I would guess that *if you were fanatical about not allowing any new features* to creep into the design, you could get everything down by 20-30%. Airframes haven't gotten hugely lighter over the last 50 years. Pure digital control systems are much smaller, but you still need power electronics to drive mechanical actuators, and those won't be much different. You still need consumables for 3 men x 2 weeks, etc. Figure on sending 35 tons into TLI, rather than 47 tons. You'll need a methane upper stage for Falcon Heavy.

Comment: @RussellBorogove thanks, yes the idea would be to mostly avoid new features for apples-to-almost-apples. Without solar panels or RTGs, I guess those LH2/LOX fuel cells would have to stay?

Comment: Even without new features, just complying with current NASA safety standards would give you the 180%

Comment: Solar panels might let you cut weight some, actually

Comment: Using solar panels instead of fuel cells means you have to carry drinking water instead of taking it off the cells. The engineering of anything as complex as the Apollo CSM is, well, complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSM/LM weight is [dominated by propellants](http://hdl.handle.net/2060/19690022248). CAD might allow you to reduce structural weight a bit, although from the description, they were already using e.g. milled skin panels to minimize structural weight. Electronics is where the biggest gains will be, but the stack has a limited amount of computers.

The biggest gain would come from replacing the engines with higher-Isp ones, which would drop the propellant weight.

What's needed for a better answer is a weight breakdown by subsystem of the CSM and LM, but I haven't found that yet.

Comment: A low pressure tank could not be used if very simple and reliable pressure feed should be used again.

Comment: The ISP of the Apollo engines is quite good for storable hypergolics; pump-fed engines would be heavier for only a small Isp gain. You'd only get appreciable gains by going to hydrogen-oxygen, which means you need a different thermal solution, which brings you dangerously close to "complete redesign" territory. There's some breakdown of the CM mass in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module if you want to take a stab at it. ntrs and history.nasa.gov will have all the numbers but they're going to be spread across dozens of docs...

Comment: Note also that while the mass is dominated by propellant, the required propellant mass should drop about linearly as you take mass off other parts.

Comment: Why does hypergolics imply low pressure tanks? Most hypergolic upper stage engine systems are pressure-fed, as was the Service Propulsion System.  I would think the engine design drives the tank design, not the propellant.

Comment: (at)RussellBorogove has an excellent point! That the weight might be dominated by propellants is irrelevant. Lower the collective weight of everything which is non-propellant bye 30%, and the required propellent will also scale by 30%. ["**Tryanny**" of the Rocket Equation](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition30/tryanny.html) (that's what the title and the url say!)

Comment: Using hydrolox engines and propellant from lunar water ice will give you the most capability. Not needing to bring the return propellant with you is a huge win. Look at Dr. Robert Zubrin's "Moon Direct" plan. The Apollo stack worked for the mission it accomplished, but it is not efficient for long term missions (months or years) that will allow real development.

Answer (score -3):

I reckon it would be a quarter of the weight.  The computers alone in the original Apollo landers must've weighed 100kg.  Think now that we have the same computing power in a mobile phone! if not more.  Yes they'd have redundant triple back up systems with data storage that is RAID'd but even then if they had 10kg of computer equipment just to match what they did in the Apollo days I'd be surprised.  Light composites and incredibly tiny gyroscopes (Ring-laser gyro's now weight next to nothing by comparison).  However the ISS still carries incredibly heavy gyro's for station stabilisation so that might be an inaccurate assumption upon my part.
All I can think is that whatever weight they'd be saving with new model landers would be made up for with the increased weights in many other areas (e.g. more fuel).
Be fascinating to see what they come up with.  I used to remember a TV show way back when, called 'Space 1999', and the Lunar transporters they had on that show were really cool.  Hope someone designs something like that in the future! :)

Comment: In order to support an estimate of "one quarter" of the original weight, it might be better to focus on components that represent a large fraction of the weight, rather than a few specific items that are only a small part of it.